# Render R Script in Tufte output with R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown

Quick question: how can I render an R Script (so, a set of function) with R Markdown, using the tufte style?

Let's say that `"myscript.R"` is the file in which I have my chunk of code.

Currently I use this syntax to generate a pdf:

```
rmarkdown::render("myscript.r", "pdf_document")
```

How can I pass to this string the info to format the pdf document according to the tufte style?

Comment: Or you can manually edit the Tufte template with your R script in Rstudio using Rmarkdown

Answer (score 0):

You could have the tufte style Rmarkdown document as a template, and then source in your Rscript.R in order to PDF from the console.

`tufte.Rmd` That was Rstudio Tufte Template.

````
---
title: "A Tufte Handout Example"
runningheader: "Tufte Handout with R Markdown" # only for pdf output
subtitle: "An implementation in R Markdown" # only for html output
author: "test"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  tufte::tufte_html: default
  tufte::tufte_handout:
    citation_package: natbib
    latex_engine: xelatex
  tufte::tufte_book:
    citation_package: natbib
    latex_engine: xelatex
bibliography: skeleton.bib
link-citations: yes
---


```{r, results='asis'}
source('myscript.R')
```
````

`myscript.R`

```
library(knitr)
print(kable(mtcars))
```

And with both of these files in the same exact directory, I can run the

```
rmarkdown::render("tufte.Rmd", output_format = "pdf_document")
```

[image]

The tufte template has a lot of formatting, but this was a simple example.

Comment: Actually, that pdf was not in tufte style?